# Paypal IPN not being fired

Tags: asp.net, paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox, paypal-subscriptions

I have the below form sent to Paypal's sandbox from my production Server

```
<form method="post" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" name="paypalFOrm">
<input type="hidden" value="_xclick-subscriptions" name="cmd">
<input type="hidden" value="a.user@gmail.com" name="business">
<input type="hidden" value="A Subscription" name="item_name">
<input type="hidden" value="10" name="item_number">
<input type="hidden" value="USD" name="currency_code">
<input type="hidden" value="1" name="no_note">
<input type="hidden" value="10" name="a3">
<input type="hidden" value="1" name="p3">
<input type="hidden" value="M" name="t3">
<input type="hidden" value="http://a.com/ThankYou.aspx?from=pc" name="return">
<input type="hidden" value="http://a.com/IPN.aspx" name="notify_url">
<input type="hidden" value="1" name="src">
<input type="image" alt="" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_subscribe_SM.gif" name="submit">
<img border="0" width="1" height="1" alt="" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif">
```

When I test the IPN using IPN simulator, it works fine however when I make test payments, no IPN is fired. Please advise if I am doing something wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subscriptions won't work from notify_url.  You'll have to setup IPN in the PayPal account profile to trigger subscription based IPNs.

Comment: I don't think so. notify_url has higher priority than the ones set in Paypal account profile. Any link that states what you have said?

Comment: That is the case for the majority of the IPNs, yes.  With subscriptions, though, it falls to the profile.

Comment: Are you sure? The IPNs have started firing again after it was queued for a day in sandbox. Still not sure what you said is true. Can you share some link that describes this?

Comment: The original subscr_signup might trigger to your notify_ipn URL, but any subsequent payments or actions related to that profile will only be triggered to what you have setup in your PayPal profile.  I know this from many years of experience with PayPal APIs and IPN.

Comment: Now that makes sense. I agree to what you've said for recurring payments. This arises a question - how can a business have 2 different IPN set for 2 different types of payment received?

Comment: You could just make the single script so it has logic to handle any type of IPN you get and do different things depending on who the receiver is.  Or, you could setup a single IPN to use from PayPal account profiles as a catch all, and then forward IPN data from there to a different URL based on the data in the IPN.

Comment: you mean a single IPN to handle all receivables by Paypal and send it to different URLs based on domains?

Comment: Sure, or based on whatever logic you need.